# Send multing large file with socket vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sockets, large-files, sendfile

I'm coding an app about LAN chat, i want to send multing file large synchronous with the same port, how to do now? i just can send multing file with case 1 file 1 port :( please help me, thanks.

Comment: A socket has a so called backlog propertie, which describes how many 'simuntanous' client connections it can handle. Of course to handle these, you migh want to look into async socket connections.

Comment: Ok, look. There are tons of tutorials out there on how to do that... If you want help, show us your code so far, then we can point out to you what you need to change/improve/refactor etc.